# How to rewrite two URL's to the same endpoint via nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian, rewrite, url

I have two HTTP endpoint as follow

```
http://me11.example.local/api/foo

http://me11.example.local/api/boo
```

I want to redirect them to two different endpoints. In my config file it works for only one URL. how do I configure this for both endpoints?
my Nginx config file looks as below

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name me11.example.local;

  location /{
   rewrite ^/api/foo / last;
   proxy_pass http:localhost:5000;
      }
 location /{
   rewrite ^/api/boo / last;
   proxy_pass http:localhost:6000;
      }
}
```

With this config I received the following error

```
duplicate location and so on
```

If I remove one location block it works fine but I need this to function for both endpoints.

How would I solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

you can try something similar to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name me11.example.local;

    if ($request_uri = "/api/foo") {
        rewrite ^/api/foo / last;
        proxy_pass http:localhost:5000;
    }
    if ($request_uri = "/api/boo") {
        rewrite ^/api/boo / last;
        proxy_pass http:localhost:6000;
    }
}
```

but watch out for the if in nginx: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

you can check nginx.conf variables here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

Regards,